# Intuitive way to think of the angle between planes

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I'm about to teach a lesson on "The angle between planes". I'm having some question on the angle between two planes definition.

Many places defines the angle between two planes as *the angle between theirs normal vector*.

When the two planes are intersected, we have a property to calculate the angle. That is: draw two lines, one in the first plane, one in the second plane and they all perpendicular to the intersection line. The angle between that 2 lines are equal to the angle of two normal vectors, which also equal the angle of two planes.

To me, the property above feels more intuitive when we talk about the angle between two planes. When people want to calculate the angle between the ladder and the floor, in my opinion, nobody would find the normal vectors and calculate the angle and they often refer to the angle mentioned in the property.

[image]

So my question is: What is the intuition of using normal vectors to define the angle between planes? Is there some real life application behind that definition or is it just a mathematical convinience?

And, another little question: How the angle between planes are applied in our real life, especially the case where the two planes are not perpendicular?

Thanks for your reading and thanks for any comments, ideas.

Comment: Apparently, it's useful in Chemistry, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_angle).

Comment: Your construction entails (1) finding the line of intersection of the two planes in question, (2) determining a third plane perpendicular to this line, and (3) constructing the appropriate triangle to calculate desired measurements. That's a lot of work! The normals approach has the advantage that one can read normal vectors right from plane equations, and then effortlessly calculate the appropriate dot-product formula for the cosine of the angle. ... Put another way: Your description actually *defines* the angle; normals give a practical way to calculate it. (Geometry shows the equivalence.)

Comment: I just happened to answer a question using the angle between planes and calculating it via the normal vectors: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4392122. That would have been quite a hassle if I'd taken the other approach.

Comment: @Blue I forgot to mentioned. My students haven't learnt solid geometry with analytic tools like plane equation so proabably I can't explain that way to them. Also, I agree with you that the property can somehow equivalent to the definition.

Comment: @joriki So I guess that the definition using normal vectors can be analytically easier for calculating and generalizing, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, at least in this case it was.